# prevent default page from loading until button clicked

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I have data submission form which i submit using ajax post, on success i want a message box to show success, it does this but only stays on screen for like a second and loads the page defaults. How can i prevent loading page default until the user clicks ok? This works with the default javascript alert box

```
function sendToController()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "JSON",
        data: JSON.stringify({ methodParam: arrayDetails }),
        success: function (result) {
            bootbox.confirm("This is the default confirm!",
                function(result) {
                    console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);                                 
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert(test);
        }
    });
}

event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: where is `event` defined here. You've used event.preventDefault(); which is required to stop default postback behaviour, but you need to actually have that variable available to you (usually from the "click" or "submit" event callback which caused this code to run. Show how you actually trigger this function.

Comment: Also, having reformatted your code, it appears that a) this snippet is incomplete and wouldn't  compile on its own, and b) event.preventDefault() is outside your sendToController() function, so it's not clear when exactly it gets executed. As it stands there's not enough info to answer the question for certain, please edit your code sample so we can see what's happening properly

Comment: @cmcc8712, is the method `sendToController` called on click of a button?

Comment: yes this is called from a submit button

Comment: Look at the answer I have just provided. Also, what ADyson said in his first comment is the real problem, though you could follow another approach that does not use preventDefault in your scenario.

Comment: It works with a default javascript alert because that is synchronous; bootbox' response is asyncronous so it doesn't pause execution of the current thread until a response is received; it instead passes right through, and invokes the callback when done.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but my best guess is that you are calling the function `sendToController` when a button is clicked to submit a form.  If that is the case, then you need to wireup the JavaScript onclick event of submit button so the form does not post back. You could use either of the 2 approaches below to solve your problem.

**Approach 1 (using return false)**

Since in your scenario there is no return false statement, so the form posts to the server and your current page reloads which in turn causes your bootbox confirm popup to vanish.

Note that you should return a false when a button is clicked if you do not want to post the form. Also, remove event.preventDefault() from your sendToController function, if using this approach, as it may cause unexpected effects.

```
<input type="button" id"btnSubmit" onclick="sendToController(); return false;" />
```

**Approach 2 (using preventDefault)**

Also, as mentioned by ADyson, you are not passing an `event` parameter to `sendToController function  and that is why when you call event.preventDefault() it does not do what you want. If you pass event to sendToController function then it will work as expected and not submit the form, without returning false. Your markup for event wiring when using preventDefault approach should look like below.

```
<input type="button" id"btnSubmit" onclick="sendToController(event);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, it's not clear exactly how your code is being called, although you mentioned it's based on the click of a button.

It ought to look something like this, in order to work properly with the `event.preventDefault()` method, and thus prevent a postback from happening simultaneously to your ajax request, which seems to be what is happening currently. You have to take the `event` variable provided to you in the callback and use that to stop the regular postback.

Assuming you have a button like either this:

```
<input type="submit" id="yourButtonID" value="Submit"/>
```

or this:

```
<button id="yourButtonID">Submit</button>
```

Then you can write this:

```
$("#yourButtonID").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  sendToController();
});

function sendToController()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "JSON",
        data: JSON.stringify({ methodParam: arrayDetails }),
        success: function (result) {
            bootbox.confirm("This is the default confirm!",
                function(result) {
                    console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);                                 
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert(test);
        }
    });
}
```